# aiogram python. Возможно ли определить какую ссылку использовал пользователь при заходе на канал Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Я пишу бота для Телеграмма и у меня в определённый момент возник вопрос: возможно ли определить по какой ссылке пользователь присоединился к каналу?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [deep_linking](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/deep_linking.html?highlight=link#aiogram.utils.deep_linking.get_start_link).

---

В payload закидываем какие-нибудь параметры, которые потом принимаются в обработчике команды `/start`

```
async def get_start_link(payload: str, encode=False) -> str:
    """
    Get 'start' deep link with your payload.

    If you need to encode payload or pass special characters -
        set encode as True

    :param payload: args passed with /start
    :param encode: encode payload with base64url
    :return: link
    """
    return await _create_link(
        link_type="start",
        payload=payload,
        encode=encode,
    )
```

Оно выдаст ссылку (как я понял).